# Show all content of <p> after click

Tags: html, css

I have text in `<p>` and I want to hide some last lines and show after click. But I'm only able to show uncomplete first line, add text "..see more" to click on. I didn't find how to solve it with just and only CSS.

This is my HTML:

```
<section id="related">
    <div class="inner">
        <section class="col" id="news">
            <h3><a href="#">News</a></h3>
            <h4>Some title</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam rhoncus, lacus sed tincidunt mollis,
            tellus erat mollis sapien, at ullamcorper augue nisi a justo. Praesent et tellus at lorem rhoncus venenatis
            non id velit. Nullam vestibulum arcu quis erat fermentum, sed venenatis arcu tristique. Quisque fermentum nisi sed porta fermentum. Nam tincidunt, ipsum et blandit sodales, turpis enim ultricies erat, a viverra tellus elit vitae enim. Etiam placerat enim orci, nec pulvinar lorem vehicula ac. Etiam eget elementum sem. Integer nisi elit, bibendum vitae leo non, posuere tincidunt neque.</p>
            <strong>10 Dec 2014</strong>
            <h4>Some title</h4>
            <p>Vestibulum luctus nibh non risus semper consectetur. Sed laoreet eget metus in elementum. Ut mollis
            faucibus risus a faucibus. Vestibulum eget maximus purus. Maecenas vitae ipsum mattis augue feugiat
            rutrum. Sed tortor eros, convallis vitae libero vitae, commodo lobortis lacus. Duis condimentum consectetur
            augue, vel pharetra orci aliquam sit amet.</p>
            <strong>5 Jan 2015</strong>
        </section>
    </div>
</section>
```

And my CSS with unsolved problem:

```
#related .inner .col p {
    white-space: nowrap;
    /*height: 50px;*/
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: clip;
}

#related .inner .col p::after {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 15px;
    content: "..see more..";
    color: #36C7E3;
}
```

And this is how it should look like:

[image]

[Here is the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bimbochobot/e3Lvdz7r/).

Note: I cannot modify HTML code, I can modify only CSS. Is there any solution please?

Comment: no problem with some jquery?

Comment: @pedram OP says they need a CSS only anwser. As for the question, try this link: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/ and linked from this: https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/hub/blogs/ellipse-my-text/

Comment: You might find this [article](http://hackingui.com/front-end/a-pure-css-solution-for-multiline-text-truncation/) useful. He explains several techniques and includes a CSS only solution as well.

Comment: The text can be truncated, the main problem is how to detect click event without using javascript. What about detecting hove over instead?

Comment: @derloopkat hover would be nice to, is it possible to do it with hover??

Comment: Yes https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/366/

Comment: @NenadVracar amazing, thank you for your time, helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You may try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/e3Lvdz7r/9/)

It's possible by hover.

```
 #related .inner .col p:hover{
  overflow: auto;
 }
```

I am not sure how to implement `click` with css.

```css
#related {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 160px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #3f5673;
    color: white;
}

#related .inner .abox .thumb {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#related .inner .abox .thumb .sgn {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 15px;
    color: #36C7E3;
}

#related .inner a {
    color: white;
}

#related .inner h3, h4 {
    color: white;
}

#related .inner .col {
  float: left;
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

#related .inner .col strong {
    padding-left: 15px;
    color: #36C7E3;
}

#related .inner .col p {
    white-space: nowrap;
    /*height: 50px;*/
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: clip;
}

#related .inner .col p::after {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 15px;
    content: "..see more..";
    color: #36C7E3;
}

#related .inner .col p:hover{
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="related">
 <div class="inner">
  <section class="col" id="news">
   <h3><a href="#">News</a></h3>
    <h4>Some title</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam rhoncus, lacus sed tincidunt mollis,
    tellus erat mollis sapien, at ullamcorper augue nisi a justo. Praesent et tellus at lorem rhoncus venenatis
    non id velit. Nullam vestibulum arcu quis erat fermentum, sed venenatis arcu tristique. Quisque fermentum nisi sed porta fermentum. Nam tincidunt, ipsum et blandit sodales, turpis enim ultricies erat, a viverra tellus elit vitae enim. Etiam placerat enim orci, nec pulvinar lorem vehicula ac. Etiam eget elementum sem. Integer nisi elit, bibendum vitae leo non, posuere tincidunt neque.
    </p>
    <strong>10 Dec 2014</strong>
    <h4>Some title</h4>
    <p>Vestibulum luctus nibh non risus semper consectetur. Sed laoreet eget metus in elementum. Ut mollis
    faucibus risus a faucibus. Vestibulum eget maximus purus. Maecenas vitae ipsum mattis augue feugiat
    rutrum. Sed tortor eros, convallis vitae libero vitae, commodo lobortis lacus. Duis condimentum consectetur
    augue, vel pharetra orci aliquam sit amet.</p>
    <strong>5 Jan 2015</strong>
  </section>
 </div>
</section>
```

You can change width of `p` element while hovering if needed.

Comment: This looks great and is it possible to show text in paragraph? Like to to automaticlly change height of div and show all text?

Comment: Yea. It is possible. Just set height while hovering

Answer (score 0):

I think you should "toggleClass" in jQuery. This is [My code](https://jsfiddle.net/easywebsitesmaker/ats44qd4/)

I added class "ewm-hidden" replare for your code css

```
#related .inner .col p {
    white-space: nowrap;
    /*height: 50px;*/
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: clip;
}
```

Equals

```
#related .inner .col p.ewm-hidden {
    white-space: nowrap;
    /*height: 50px;*/
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: clip;
}
```

HTML:

```
<section id="related">
    <div class="inner">
        <section class="col" id="news">
            <h3><a href="#">News</a></h3>
                <h4>Some title</h4>
                <p class="ewm-hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam rhoncus, lacus sed tincidunt mollis,
                tellus erat mollis sapien, at ullamcorper augue nisi a justo. Praesent et tellus at lorem rhoncus venenatis
                non id velit. Nullam vestibulum arcu quis erat fermentum, sed venenatis arcu tristique. Quisque fermentum nisi sed porta fermentum. Nam tincidunt, ipsum et blandit sodales, turpis enim ultricies erat, a viverra tellus elit vitae enim. Etiam placerat enim orci, nec pulvinar lorem vehicula ac. Etiam eget elementum sem. Integer nisi elit, bibendum vitae leo non, posuere tincidunt neque.
                </p>
                <strong>10 Dec 2014</strong>
                <h4>Some title</h4>
                <p class="ewm-hidden">Vestibulum luctus nibh non risus semper consectetur. Sed laoreet eget metus in elementum. Ut mollis
                faucibus risus a faucibus. Vestibulum eget maximus purus. Maecenas vitae ipsum mattis augue feugiat
                rutrum. Sed tortor eros, convallis vitae libero vitae, commodo lobortis lacus. Duis condimentum consectetur
                augue, vel pharetra orci aliquam sit amet.</p>
                <strong>5 Jan 2015</strong>
        </section>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#related {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 160px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #3f5673;
    color: white;
}

#related .inner .abox .thumb {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#related .inner .abox .thumb .sgn {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 15px;
    color: #36C7E3;
}

#related .inner a {
    color: white;
}

#related .inner h3, h4 {
    color: white;
}

#related .inner .col {
  float: left;
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

#related .inner .col strong {
    padding-left: 15px;
    color: #36C7E3;
}

#related .inner .col p.ewm-hidden {
    white-space: nowrap;
    /*height: 50px;*/
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: clip;
}

#related .inner .col p::after {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 15px;
    content: "..see more..";
    color: #36C7E3;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$( ".col p" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "ewm-hidden" );
});
```

Comment: From the question: "*I cannot modify HTML code, I can modify only CSS.*" This suggests that the classes cannot be added, nor jQuery - or any other JavaScript - added or linked-to.

Comment: Note that I never said it was possible (though I think it mostly is), I just said that your answer didn't meet the specified criteria in the hope that you might edit it to better answer the question and, ultimately, accrue some up-votes to gain some reputation and enhance your experience here.

Answer (score 0):

**This for you :**

```css
.read-more-state {
  display: none;
}

.read-more-target {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
}

.read-more-state:checked ~ .ewm-hidden .read-more-target {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
}

.read-more-state ~ .read-more-trigger:before {
  content: '...SeeMore...';
}

.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-trigger:before {
  content: '...Show less...';
}

.read-more-trigger {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  color: #666;
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 2;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: .25em;
}
```

```html
<section id="related">
    <div class="inner">
        <section class="col" id="news">
            <h3><a href="#">News</a></h3>
            <div>

                <h4>Some title</h4>
                <input type="checkbox" class="read-more-state" id="post-1" />
                <p class="ewm-hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam rhoncus, lacus sed tincidunt mollis,
                <span class="read-more-target">
                tellus erat mollis sapien, at ullamcorper augue nisi a justo. Praesent et tellus at lorem rhoncus venenatis
                non id velit. Nullam vestibulum arcu quis erat fermentum, sed venenatis arcu tristique. Quisque fermentum nisi sed porta fermentum. Nam tincidunt, ipsum et blandit sodales, turpis enim ultricies erat, a viverra tellus elit vitae enim. Etiam placerat enim orci, nec pulvinar lorem vehicula ac. Etiam eget elementum sem. Integer nisi elit, bibendum vitae leo non, posuere tincidunt neque.
                </span> </p>
                <strong>10 Dec 2014</strong>
                 <label for="post-1" class="read-more-trigger"></label>
                 </div>
                 <div>
                 
                 
                <h4>Some title</h4>
                <input type="checkbox" class="read-more-state" id="post-2" />
                <p class="ewm-hidden">Vestibulum luctus nibh non risus semper consectetur. Sed laoreet eget metus in elementum. Ut mollis
                faucibus risus a faucibus. Vestibulum eget maximus purus.<span class="read-more-target"> Maecenas vitae ipsum mattis augue feugiat
                rutrum. Sed tortor eros, convallis vitae libero vitae, commodo lobortis lacus. Duis condimentum consectetur
                augue, vel pharetra orci aliquam sit amet.</span></p>
                <strong>5 Jan 2015</strong>
                <label for="post-2" class="read-more-trigger"></label></div>
        </section>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: thank you for response solution but I cannot modify HTML code. but it can be on hover instead of click event